# How to set the position of textView using X and y coordinates

Tags: java, android, xml, textview

I tried using the drag and drop function but when the program runs, the textView objects go to 0,0. How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Please specify in details your question. Such as your XML.

Comment: I've suggested an edit which gives a more detailed explanation of the problem I believe you to be having. I hope it has helped in addition to the answer I provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly, you need to use constraints. For example, say you have this `editText` object:

[image: unconstrained editText]

You could set it so that it is a specified number of `dp`, or Density Independent Pixels, from another object e.g. the left white circle (drag and drop to create constraints) of the `editText` box could be dragged to the edge on the left which would constrain it to that edge. You then tell it to be so many `dp` away, say `20dp` from the left so it appears like so:

[image: editText constrained 20px from left]

You can change the value of the constraint's `dp` in the right-hand `Properties` column which would show like this:

[image: Properties column]

You would then change the 8 to 20.

In addition, you can set these constraints programmatically in the XML code by adding the statement such as:

`android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"`

within the object's code making it look like this:
[image: Code with constraint]

As I'm sure you can tell, the examples I've given have constrained the object to the left bound/edge of the screen. You can also set constraints based on other objects surrounding the one you wish to constrain as well as parent objects. You then add constraints to the top, right and down positions as needed.

Hope I've explained it well enough and that it helps you.